# Was The Doctor naked all the time on Trenzalore?

Tags: doctor-who

In *The Time of The Doctor*, The Doctor went naked to Papal Mainframe wearing holographic clothes which was projected directly into the visual cortex of selected people. From Papal Mainframe, he teleported down to the planet naked (I remember him saying to Clara that heat filter of holographic clothes would kick in soon). Was he naked all the time on Trenzalore?

If yes, why didn't people in the Christmas notice that? Did writers forget about that at that point?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a line in the [transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/33-16.html) that indicates that they put on real clothes before exiting the TARDIS on Trenzalore:

> [Town]
>
> CLARA: Oh, it's good to be wearing clothes again. That's so much
>   better, don't you think?
>
> (They are dressed for the weather. The Doctor scans everything with
>   his screwdriver. The trees are decorated with lights so the village
>   has electricity at least.)

Technically only Clara mentions wearing clothes, but "That's so much better, don't you think?" seems to indicate she expected the Doctor to agree that it felt better to be wearing clothes again.

Comment: Oh sorry. He also summoned TARDIS on Trenzalore after becoming Picard. I did forget about that.